# margin-top:-15px (negative pixels) in html not working in Outlook

Tags: html, css, outlook

I want to apply margin top and bottom to `<hr>` tag in the email body, but it is not getting reflated to outlook email.
Below is the code I want to apply:

```
<hr style='margin-bottom:-15px;margin-top:-15cm;color:#333;'/>
```

Please help me to get some workaround to this.

Comment: Have a look at this Litmus article https://litmus.com/help/email-clients/outlookcom-margins/

Comment: Many of the CSS properties doesn't work in Microsoft Outlook simply because its rendering engine doesn't support them. A good source to look at is: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa338201(v=office.12).aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [this article](https://litmus.com/blog/hotmail-and-outlook-com-drop-support-for-margin), Outlook no longer supports `margins`. As an alternative you could wrap your `hr` element in a wrapper that is as high as your desired `margin-top` + `margin-bottom`, then offset your `hr` element by `margin-top` from the top.

In the example below I used `10px` as `margin-top` and `20px` as `margin-bottom` because I wouldn't know what `15px` + `15cm` equals =)

```css
.hr-wrapper {
  position: relative;
  /* the height should be your margin-top + margin-bottom, e.g. 10px + 20px */
  height: 30px; 
}

hr {
  position: absolute;
  /* that's where your margin-top goes. The rest of the wrapper's height
  will contribute to margin-bottom */
  top: 10px;
  margin: 0; /* this is just for the browser where margin works */
  width: 100%;
}

/* These divs are just for show */
div:not(.hr-wrapper){
  background-color: goldenrod;
  height: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div></div>

<div class="hr-wrapper">
    <hr>
</div>

<div></div>
```

Comment: According https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/ neither `position` works in Outlook 2007/10/13. Is this really solution?

Comment: @myf I didn't know that :( Apparently this would still not work in Outlook, then.

Answer (score 4):

HTML emails are incredibly annoying. You can not rely on a huge number of the features of modern-day CSS if you want your email to render properly in the majority of email clients.

Here is a tiny subset of things to **avoid**:

- `position`
- `float`
- `margin`
- `display`

There are *plenty* more.

Basically, [use nested tables](https://templates.mailchimp.com/development/html/) for your layout. They're the only thing that will give you consistent rendering across email clients.

[Dreamweaver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adobe_Dreamweaver) is a very good tool for helping you to compose a nested table structure without having to manually write the HTML. I don't know whether there's a similar product available for free.

If you're targeting mobiles - [and you should be](https://litmus.com/blog/53-of-emails-opened-on-mobile-outlook-opens-decrease-33) - you **can** use media queries. Within those queries you may be able to get away with some more recent CSS features but err on the side of caution.